# Advantage of segue through UINavigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

What is the advantage of using `UINavigationController` between a segue from one `ViewController` to `ViewController` ?

One could do it without a `UINavigationController` as well. And add a navigation bar and back buttons separately

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The advantage of using UINavigationController between a segue from one ViewController to ViewController is that you can return previous ViewController by using UINavigationItem.

Like this,

[image]

This is why you don't need to implement transition. But this is one of the reasons.

If you want to know more details about UINavigationController, you can see that.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/

There are many useful methods in UINavigationController.

As a result, which is better to use UINavigationController's segue or just segue depends on your situation. If you don't know which is better, ask a question in stackoverflow again.

Answer (score 0):

`UINavigationController` provides a Navigation Stack. You just push `UIViewControllers` but without extra afford you won't get an navigation which `UINavigationController` provides (back button and other stuff) and what most users expects when using an app